# Search Excel column value with other column record

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I want to search each area record with "accountarea" record. E.g.: A narayanapura; KR puram should be searched in "accountarea" column. If the value exists, print `true`.

Comment: Did you consider sharing the column structure of your excel?

Comment: It seems you tried to upload an image, but it was not uploaded. Please use [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31108791/edit) button to do so, unless the existent answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "accountarea" column is column A, try

=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"A narayanapura; KR puram"),TRUE,"")